# Inserting Element before another element Using CSS

Tags: c#, css

I have the following code that is generated dynamically using ASP.NET MVC Razor engine:

```
<p class="line-item">COLOR</p>
<p class="line-item">HEIGHT</p>
<p class="line-item">WIDTH</p>
```

Now, I want somehow to move the WIDTH

before height. So this is what I want:

```
<p class="line-item">COLOR</p>
<p class="line-item">WIDTH</p>
<p class="line-item">HEIGHT</p>
```

I want to use CSS or minimal code for this. If this does not work then I will have to change it in C# code.

Comment: Are you OK using JavaScript? It sounds to me like you want to alter the DOM which is beyond styling the page. Presentation is the domain of CSS, altering semantic markup generally belongs in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the best solution is to just do this in the backend and send the correct data/items to begin with.

Comment: if this code is generated with Razor then why not to fix it before returning to the client?

Comment: I would agree, ordering it in the backend is better from a consistency and readability perspective. I could imagine, a year from now, someone saying "But I'm sending them in the Color, Height, Width order, why they heck are they getting swapped???" and wasting a few hours to track it down.

Comment: You can CSS3 feature `Flex`

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS3 features `Flex` method. Using a `Flex` and `order`property you can change the sequence of content as well. see the support [can i use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
div{display:flex; flex-flow: column;}
p:nth-child(1){order:0;}
p:nth-child(2){order:2;}
p:nth-child(3){order:1;}
```

```html
 <div>
  <p class="line-item">COLOR</p>
<p class="line-item">HEIGHT</p>
<p class="line-item">WIDTH</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem is, this solves his problem given the input he described. However, his statement was "move width before height." If I suddenly had 5 `p` tags, your code would break because it's not putting it before height, it's putting it in a particular ordinal. Not sure if that meets his needs. If his backend is just "here's 3 static things" I can't imagine he wouldn't have just reordered them already...

Comment: @dman2306 you may be right. I don't know actual situation there are multiple `p` tags or few tags. But OP want to know that is possible or not to change sequence just using CSS.

Comment: Fair enough, and certainly a good technique to share (I didn't know about this so I learned something new too). I just wanted to point out to the OP to be careful to make sure this works in all necessary situations.

Comment: @dman2306 good thing is all latest browsers support these new CSS3 features. and very good support for mobile browser. May be you heard about Mobile first approach. We can change the sequence of content for mobile and for desktop based browsers.

Comment: I sure have, of course I also work in a world where IE8 still exists :(

Comment: unfortunately IE8 and IE9 doesn't support this features. :(

Comment: @john doe if this solution works for you. you should accept the answer and upvote for future reference.

Comment: @john doe to close this question you should accept the answer so it could be helpful for people looking for same problem in near future.

Answer (score 0):

After it is generated on the page and the DOM has been loaded you cannot change it via CSS you would have to use JQuery/JavaScript for that.

If you want to sort it with CSS on load then I would highly suggest doing that in the back end for **reliability and maintenance reasons**.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing it in C#.

Technically, if these items always have a fixed height, you could make them `position: relative;` and move one up by setting something like `top: -18px` and the other down by setting something like `top: 18px`, but this would be very prone to error.

The only real way to change the order of flowing elements in CSS would be to make them use the [flex box model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and have them flow vertically. Then you can set the `order` property to make some elements appear before others. See the link for a full explanation. This might be way too much work for simply changing the order of two elements, however, which is why I think you should change it in C# instead.

If C# really isn't an option, then you can of course also change the order of the elements using JavaScript (I'd recommend looking into `insertBefore` which would let you move the element with just one call), but again that seems like a lot of hassle compared to simply changing the order in C#.